# How to run GDB from PHP and pass it RUN and BACKTRACE commands?

Tags: php, gdb

We write a Web Interface for C++ programming olympiad in our school. We call students's executables with `popen` and write to their inputs with `fprintf`. The output is redirected to a special file and we can read it without problems. But we cannot run GDB and pass it RUN and BACKTRACE commands using `popen` and `fprintf`. I mean `fprintf(gdb_handle, "%s", "backtrace")` and `fprintf(gdb_handle, "%s", "run")` don't work at all. Are there any special ways to pass RUN and BACKTRACE to GDB?

Comment: You probably need to send a newline as well.  If you really want to drive gdb, though, you  may want to investigate "MI", gdb's machine interface.  It provides a more reliable program-oriented interface to gdb, and is what all the IDEs use.